# How are these two question(s) different

Tags: discussion

How are these question about personal finance

[Why are both government and commercial bond prices rising?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3188/why-are-both-government-and-commercial-bond-prices-rising?rq=1)

[Why is my corporate bond portfolio decreasing when my stock portfolio is increasing?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5174/why-is-my-corporate-bond-portfolio-decreasing-when-my-stock-portfolio-is-increas?rq=1)

[Why does interest rate go up when bond price goes down?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9853/why-does-interest-rate-go-up-when-bond-price-goes-down?rq=1)

and this is not

https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/36483/effect-of-increasing-house-prices-on-my-economic-situation

My question is closed because it's not about personal finance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Let me welcome you to the site.

Don't take it too hard to have a question closed, everybody does.  Our goal is to make the Internet better.  I have had questions and answers closed and deleted too; it is just a part of the process.

## Why the question was closed

**First:** The question is still about your economic situation.  Yes, you are personally affected, but what can you really do about it?  Or, more specifically, what can people generally do about it?  (Move?  Deal with it?)  The information as to "why" you seek is academic (very interesting, I think many of us here enjoy economics as much as you seem to) but economics are generally off topic.

The reason (in my opinion) the financial literacy about bonds is still open is the action-abilty.  When we compare your examples about bond prices, visitors here can do something to their portfolio based on the knowledge they got from the answer.  When they know the economic effects of why their housing is more expensive, the realistic options for most people are "deal with it" or political.

**Second:** the post was closed before all the edits.  Based on what I saw for the original versions it certainly was off topic.  Interesting, but off topic for our site.

**Third:**  the community reviewed your edits as a candidate for re-open and it didn't pass.

**Finally:**  you found some old questions.  One of them does seem off-topic by our current standards.  We have grown and shifted as a community over the years and there are certainly some inconsistencies between two years ago and today.  (However, your question is still valid and please don't hesitate to ask for clarification.)

## Suggestions for question writing on Money.SE

Explain what you have noticed economically, and ask about how to take advantage of the situation?  (*"Housing is a getting expensive, based on my situation, how can I take advantage of the rising prices?"*)

Ask about money saving possibilities (*"My stars it is expensive to live in downtown London, what are some proven methods to get a good deal on a lease?"*)

The key is to ask a question that has a definite answer, doesn't require a 10,0000 word essay to explain and is (as much as possible) timeless.  Writing good questions is hard.  You will notice most of the high rep people have a bunch of answers, but few questions.

Comment: Thank you for your advise, I will try to follow it :-)